# WCF OAuth - Not using RESTFUL services

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, oauth

I've done some background research into WCF services, and we've decided to look into ways of providing authentication on our services. I suggested OAuth, however we are unsure whether OAuth can be used for WCF services that are **NOT** RESTful. These would be all over SSL as well.

Can we pass OAuth variables as an object in service calls, alongside our other parameters?

i.e.

```
[OperationContract]
public void GetTheAwesome(OAuthObject oauth, AwesomeObject awesome);

[OperationContract]
public OAuthRequestObject Authorise(string username, string pass);

[OperationContract]
public OAuthObject Authenticate(OAuthRequestObject authObj);

[DataContract]
public class OAuthRequestObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ConsumerKey { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ConsumerSecret { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class OAuthObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string AccessKey { get; set; }  // our key
    [DataMember]
    public string AccessSecret { get; set; }  // our signature/secret
    [DataMember]
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }  // our timestamp
    [DataMember]
    public string SignatureMethod { get; set; }  // our signature method (HMAC/SHA, etc)
}
```

Is this a valid way for it to occur? Can OAuth even work in this way? Is OAuth restricted to RESTful calls only?

**OR**

Am I simply overcomplicating things? If I specified to our developers an explicit username/password to include in our other applications, would they function just as well?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/523/oauth-dot-net

Comment: I've already seen that link during my research adventure, and it is still using RESTful services, which I don't want to have to use.

Comment: Reading more into that, would it be safe/secure to send the OAuth variables inside an object, rather than in the header/querystring?

Comment: Putting an access token in the query string is not safe because it will be stored in a browser history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OAuth specification (section 7.1) provides an extensibility point to allow for new access token types and each token type specifies the authentication method(s) that must be used with that token. For example, the "bearer" token type specifies that the token should be attached as an Authorization header of the form "Bearer ".

Here is a link to the spec:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

And here is an snippet from it:

> The access token type provides the client with the information required to successfully utilize the access token to make a protected resource request (along with type-specific attributes).  The client MUST NOT use an access token if it does not understand the token type.
>
> For example, the "bearer" token type defined in [RFC6750] is utilized by simply including the access token string in the request:
>
> ```
>  GET /resource/1 HTTP/1.1
>  Host: example.com
>  Authorization: Bearer mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM
> ```
>
> while the "mac" token type defined in [OAuth-HTTP-MAC] is utilized by issuing a Message Authentication Code (MAC) key together with the access token that is used to sign certain components of the HTTP requests:
>
> ```
>  GET /resource/1 HTTP/1.1
>  Host: example.com
>  Authorization: MAC id="h480djs93hd8",
>                     nonce="274312:dj83hs9s",
>                     mac="kDZvddkndxvhGRXZhvuDjEWhGeE="
> ```
>
> The above examples are provided for illustration purposes only. Developers are advised to consult the [RFC6750] and [OAuth-HTTP-MAC] specifications before use.
>
> Each access token type definition specifies the additional attributes (if any) sent to the client together with the "access_token" response parameter. It also defines the HTTP authentication method used to    include the access token when making a protected resource request.

If you are going to implement the Authorisation Server for your services then you are free to define any token type that you want as well as an authentication scheme. Beware of interoperability though. As described, your service will only work with SOAP capable clients and third parties will probably find you a bit hard to deal with.

If you are using an existing 3rd party Authorisation Server, then they will define the token type and you should comply with their authentication scheme.

**WS-Trust option**

As you are in a .Net/WCF/SOAP world, a better option might be to use WS-Trust/WS-Federation. This is very well supported in WCF with Windows Identity Foundation (WIF). Depending on which .Net version you are using, WIF is either built into the core framework (.Net 4.5) or available as a separate install (.Net 3.5 and 4).

The basic idea of it is that the requests for security tokens and the way they are inserted into SOAP requests when making service calls are standardised. This would replace the `Authorise` and `Authenticate` operations with standard ones and replace your explicit `OAuthObject` parameter with a standard SOAP security header.

Under the hood it is complex, but the WIF implementation abstracts all the complexity away beautifully in my opinion.

An overview can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291066(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I probably should have added in my main post that a lot of our other applications are coded in Delphi, outside the .Net wonderland. So does this restrict the possible use of WIF? On another note, restricting to a SOAP environment isn't too bad for us, as we never want "outside" clients developing with our services. It's more for our internally developed applications being used by external customers, where we want them to use our central databases.

Comment: Well, parts of WIF just deal with implementing the relevant WS-* protocols, so .Net/WIF in that case is just a convenience not a pre-requisite. I know very little about Delphi and what the WS-* support is like.

Comment: Ah I see, well I know little of WIF and Delphi also (and neither do any of our Delphi developers, as they are .Net-phobes). I guess I will take a look into implementing a SOAP style authentication scheme for our services. Thank you for the excellent response though :)